# Is trace operator is invertible?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

This question come to me when I try to find the weak solution of following problem
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u =f&x\in\Omega \\\
u=g&x\in\partial\Omega
\end{cases}
where $\Omega$ is open bounded smooth boundary.

Then the usual trick we always take is to find a function $\tilde g\in H^2(\Omega)$ such that $T[\tilde g]=g$ and we study the problem
\begin{cases}
-\Delta \tilde u =f-\Delta \tilde g&x\in\Omega \\\
\tilde u=0&x\in\partial\Omega
\end{cases}
and hence we could apply Lax-Milgram and so on.

However, I want to ask that can we always find such $\tilde g$? That is, given any function $g\in L^2(\partial \Omega)$, is there always exists a function $\tilde g\in H^2(\Omega)$ such that $T[\tilde g]=g$? i.e., is that the trace operator $T$ is invertible? We know $T$: $H^2(\Omega)\to L^2(\partial\Omega)$ (actually is $H^1(\Omega)\to L^2(\partial\Omega)$) is well defined, but how about $T^{-1}$? Or is that $T$ is surjective?

Comment: I don't think $T:H^2 \to L^2$ is surjective, however $T:H^1 \to L^2$ is surjective with a right inverse. But you don't need $\bar g \in H^2$, just take it in $H^1$ so that $\langle -\Delta \bar g, v \rangle_{H^{-1}, H^1_0} = \int \nabla \bar g \nabla v$.

Comment: By one hand, there are plenty of function with the same boundary values, so it is no injective. On the other hand, the image of $T:H^1(\Omega)\to L^2(\partial\Omega)$ is $H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)$.

Comment: @Tomás so it is not surjective?

Comment: @riem could you provide a source that prove for surjectivety?

Comment: No @wisher, $T:H^1\to L^2$. It is surjective as an operator $T:H^1\to H^{1/2}$ and it has a right inverse as pointed out by riem. Take a look in Necas book: Les Methodes Directes En Theorie Des Equations Elliptiques. There is an English version of this book, however, I do prefer the French version. The English version is poorly translated.

Comment: Take a look also in this book: http://www.amazon.com/Function-Spaces-Mechanics-Analysis-Kufner/dp/9028600159/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1420701665&sr=8-1&keywords=function+spaces+kufner

Comment: @wisher Sorry I meant to write $T:H^1 \to H^{\frac 12}$ is surjective as Tomas wrote. I would recommend eg. Demengel and Demengel.

Comment: @Tomás sure I'll check out the reference you provided! However, back to my question. Since $T$ is not surjective, which means that not every $g$ we could apply this trick and obtain a solution right? It makes sense since if we have a solution, then the trace of solution has to be good, better then $L^2$ at least

Comment: @riem thanks for your answer, and please check above comment!

Comment: That's right @riem, you can only extend functions in $L^2(\partial\Omega)$ (and this extension will belong to $H^1(\Omega)$), by means of the trace operator, if and only if these functions belong to the more restrict space $H^{1/2}$.

Comment: @Tomás I understood. This makes sense. Compare to solving the boundary value problem in classical sense, I.e., by Perron method, we have to ask at least the boundary value is cont's!

Comment: @wisher Yes, you cannot say that for every $g \in L^2(\partial\Omega)$ there is an extension $\bar g \in H^2(\Omega)$. Only that for every $g \in H^{\frac 12}(\partial\Omega)$, there is a $\bar g \in H^1(\Omega)$.